# How to Append Masked Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, and I want to append them into a new array but I need the masked information to be kept. I tried numpy.append(), but it lose the masked information.

```
>>> maska
masked_array(data = [-- 1 3 2 1 -- -- 3 6],
     mask = [ True False False False False  True  True False False],
     fill_value = 0)

>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- 1 3 2],
     mask = [ True False False False], fill_value = 0)

>>> np.append(maska,b)
masked_array(data = [0 1 3 2 1 0 0 3 6 0 1 3 2],
     mask = False, fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: what happens with `np.vstack` or `np.hstack`?

Comment: same as append, losing the masked information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed very strange that even `np.ma.hstack` doesn't work, but you can achieve what you need by manually combining the masks:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: def masked_hstack(tup):
   ...:     return np.ma.masked_array(np.hstack(tup),
   ...:            mask=np.hstack([arr.mask for arr in tup]))
   ...:

In [3]: a, b = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 6], [0, 1, 3, 2]

In [4]: maska, maskb = [np.ma.masked_equal(arr, 0) for arr in a, b]

In [5]: masked_hstack((maska, maskb))
Out[5]:
masked_array(data = [-- 1 3 2 1 -- -- 3 6 -- 1 3 2],
             mask = [ True False False False False  True  True False False  True False False
 False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

You can also override the `fill_value` to be `0`, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try masked class append: `np.ma.append`

```
# make first Array
In[1]: maska = np.ma.array([999, 1,3,2,1, 999, 999, 3, 6],
                    mask = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False])
In[2]: maska
Out[2]: masked_array(data=[--, 1, 3, 2, 1, --, --, 3, 6],
                       mask=[ True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False], fill_value=999999)

# make 2nd array
In[3]: b = np.ma.array([999, 1, 3, 2], mask=[True, False, False, False])
In[4]: b
Out[4]: masked_array(data=[--, 1, 3, 2],
                     mask=[ True, False, False, False], fill_value=999999)

# Now append the two arrays 
In[5]: np.ma.append(maska, b)
Out[5]: masked_array(data=[--, 1, 3, 2, 1, --, --, 3, 6, --, 1, 3, 2],
                     mask=[ True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
               False,  True, False, False, False], fill_value=999999)
```